# Como atualizar o Index de um field usando JavaScript no Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, javascript-eventos

Estou criando campos dinamicamente com base uma List. Quando eu removo um campo, preciso reordená-los usando o javascript, mas estou enfrentando problemas, pois todos os campos são reordenados os Índices, exceto os que usam o razor "asp-validation-for"... Teria como eu dar um Find e mudar o Índice dele também?

Razor:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasDocumentosViewModel[i].Documento" class="control-label txt-documento">Documento</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasDocumentosViewModel[i].Documento" class="form-control txt-documento" />
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasDocumentosViewModel[i].Documento" class="text-danger txt-documento"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
qtdDocumentos--;
$("#div-documentos .row").each(function (indice, elemento) {
    $(elemento).find(".txt-documento").attr("name", "PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasDocumentosViewModel[" + indice + "].Documento");
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pensei em pegar todos os *elementos* de validation da página e pra cada um alterar o `name` deles de acordo com o índice.

Deste modo se você tiver outros campos validation na tela terá que optimizar a busca dos componenetes pegando diretamente de alguma div.

Talvez isso te ajude ou pelo menos te dê um norte pra seguir amigo:

```js
  function ReordenarValidation()
  {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text-danger');

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].attr("name", "PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasDocumentosViewModel["+ i +"].Documento");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado @Victor Laio :)